# Select columns based on exact string match

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I have a large dataframe which contain columns like this:

```
df <- data.frame(W0 = 1,
                 Response = 1,
                 HighResponse = 1,
                 Response.W0 = 1,
                 HighResponse.W0 =1)
```

Now, in a for loop, I want to select a column based on whether they contain a specified string- `Response`, `W0`, `HighResponse`. My method of selecting the column is:

```
x <- dplyr::select(df, contains("HighResponse.W0"))  #this works
x <- dplyr::select(df, contains("HighResponse"))  #doesn't work. Selects HighResponse and HighResponse.W0
x <- dplyr::select(df, contains("Response")) #doesn't work. Selects Response, HighResponse, Response.W0, HighResponse.W0
x <- dplyr::select(df, contains("W0"))  #doesn't work. Selects W0, Response.W0, HighResponse.W0
```

How can I modify my column selection method, so that it only selects exact string? For ex, select only `W0` or `Response` not the other matching strings.

Comment: You stated you are using these in a loop. Unless you are doing simulations where the current data points depend on the previous, you should learn to only use functions from the tidyverse package, eg-groupby, map, etc. Those will make your work neat and easily readable, and of course pipable

Comment: yes, I am doing further analysis on the selected columns.

Comment: seems you are doing the same analysis over and over. You can use `map`

Answer (score 3):

Use anchors with `matches` to specify the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string:

```r
dplyr::select(df, matches("^HighResponse$"))
```

Or, without `contains`:

```r
dplyr::select(df, "HighResponse")
```